# Sort Posts By Category?

Tags: php, sorting, loops, categories

Googled this for hours, cannot find a solution.

On my [theme](http://www.elevancement.com/themes/browse/) you have a `Browse` page which pulls all the videos from the Custom Post Type I am working with. If a user makes 30 categories then id like for users to be able to sort the videos using the Category buttons listed at the top. If they click on `Horror` id like to loop to show all `Horror` Videos.

How can I sort my videos using Categories within this loop?

**BROWSE PAGE**

My Category ul li a

```
<ul class="sort-by-category">
    <?
      $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'parent' => 0
      );
      $categories = get_categories( $args );
      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<li><a class="browse-categories" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
<? 
    // Our variables
    $numPosts = (isset($_GET['numPosts'])) ? $_GET['numPosts'] : 0;
    $page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

    query_posts(array(
          'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
          'paged'          => $page,
          'post_type'      => 'theme_video'
    ));

    // our loop
    if (have_posts()) {
          while (have_posts()){
                the_post();
                get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'browse' );
          }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
  ?>
```

I'm a bit lost on how to proceed. Nothing I tried seems to sort the loop, and the methods ive used have been outdated by 1-2 years...

Site works well for my first theme, but I do not know how to get this loop to sort by the category you select. Any tips or pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Answer has been found and I am posting it for anyone else who has this issue. If you have better ways of accomplishing this then please post below for the benefit of others.

Place this code in your **category.php.** It will automatically grab the category from the URL and pass it to the `cat => $category_id` and update the loop accordingly.

```
<ul class="sort-by-category">
<?
  $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent' => 0
  );
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<li><a class="browse-categories" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  }
?>
</ul>

<?
    // Our variables
    $page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

    // grab slug from url
    $category_id = get_query_var('cat');

    // define args
            $args = array( 
                        'posts_per_page' => '36',
          'paged'          =>  $page,
          'post_type'      => 'theme_video',
          'cat'            =>  $category_id
     );

            // place args in query
            $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

            // our loop
            if($category_posts->have_posts()) { 
            while($category_posts->have_posts()) { 
                    $category_posts->the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'browse' );
            }
    } 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```